# What is Pyramidal Time Frames?

Tags: time-series, data-mining

In my project, I need to store the clusters as snapshots by means of pyramidal time frame . I have already referred many sites but i couldn't understand how it works. Please can anyone explain this with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchical aggregation of different time frames.

Say your lowest granularity is 1 minute, then 15 minutes, 60 minutes, 6 hours, 1 day, 1 week...
You can draw them like a pyramid. 1 week is 7 days is 28 6hour frames, is 24*7hours, ...